# How to mininmise xib window in applescripts xcode project when a button on it is clicked

Tags: macos, xcode7, applescript-objc

I created an apple script xcode. Where the main.xib is a window with two buttons. When one button is clicked i am running an shell script, when another button is clicked i am running another shell script, all this part of code i added in Appdelegate.applescript.What i wanted to do here is when i am clicking on buttons still that main.xib window is staying on screen. I want to close it.Please some one help me how can achieve this by adding code on Appdelegate.applescript

```
script AppDelegate
     property parent : class "NSObject"
     -- IBOutlets
     property theWindow : missing value
         on button1Clicked_(sender)  
           do shell script " sudo example.sh" with administrator privileges

        end button1Clicked_


        on button2Clicked_(sender)


            do shell script " sudo exapmle1.sh " with administrator privileges
        end button2Clicked_


        on applicationWillFinishLaunching_(aNotification)
        -- Insert code here to initialize your application before any files are opened
        end applicationWillFinishLaunching_



        on applicationShouldTerminate_(sender)

        -- Insert code here to do any housekeeping before your application quits 
        return current application's NSTerminateNow
    end applicationShouldTerminate_
 end script
```

Please some one help me to understand whatt type of code can be added under applicationShouldTerminate and applicationwillfinishlaunching
I am new to this, please help me where can i get more information regarding this

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the window as soon as you execute a script, you could add the following to the end of each button's handler:

`theWindow's performClose:me`

You could also create a button whose handler contains only that code, so that the button will close the window.